# How do i pass drop down to a form field

Tags: javascript, html

so i have a drop down and i want to pass the value selected onto a hidden text form field. I have spent a long time looking around and am unable to find any way to do this.

I know it will be done with a javascript function but not sure how.

Here is my code currently:

```
<? $year = $_GET["year"];  
$x="SELECT  
nfw_week.week_no  
FROM  
nfw_week";  
$xx= mysql_query("$x") or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());      
?>

<div class="form-group"><label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Year for this weekly analysis:</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
<select name="weekdate" id="weekdate" class="form-control" value="" onChange="getweekdate(this.value,'<? echo $week_number ?>');">
<option id="weekdate" name="weekdate" value=""></option>

<?
 while(list($week_number)= mysql_fetch_row($xx)){
if($week_number < 10){
   $week_number = "0".$week_number;  
}
$date =  date('d/m/Y', strtotime($year."W".$week_number.$day))."\n";
$weekvanumbervalue = 'value="'.$week_number.'" '; 
$datenumbervalue = 'value="'.$date.'" ';
?>
<option <? echo $weekvanumbervalue; ?> <? echo $datenumbervalue; ?>>Date Starting: <? echo $date ?> Week Number:<? echo $week_number ?></option>
<?
}
?>
<input type="hidden" name="selectedweekhidden" id="name="selectedweekhidden"" value="">
```

so i want to somehow push what ever is selected from the drop down to be pushed into the text field id of selectedweekhidden

i have jquery loaded at top of page

Comment: What have you tried? What is your form's code? What JS framework/library are you using (or nothing)? We can't answer your question without a bit of code.

Comment: Have you made any attempt?  Breaking down the problem into discrete components, it sounds like you need to be able to 1) Get a value from a `select` and 2) Set a value on an `input`.

Comment: show us your html and desire result?

Comment: `document.getElementById('yourelement').onchange = function() { document.getElementById('yourotherelement').value = this.value; }`?

Comment: Sorry everyone, i updated question with what i currently have.

Comment: THANKS putvande!! That did the trick. So easy, i really should have thought of that.

Thank you again.

document.getElementById('weekdate').onchange = function() { document.getElementById('selectedweekhidden').value = this.value; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THANKS putvande!! That did the trick. So easy, i really should have thought of that. Thank you again. document.getElementById('weekdate').onchange = function() { document.getElementById('selectedweekhidden').value = this.value; } –